# mysql while loop returning null

Tags: mysql, while-loop, do-while

I have a table with a persons id as the primary key which contains their manager's id.  I want to set up a while loop that will display all of that person's managers ids, all the way to the top of the list.  I built a while loop, but it's returning null.  What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE FUNCTION `whilefunction`() RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN
    declare l_loop varchar(25) default '123456';
    declare result varchar(255) default '';
    while l_loop is not null do
        set result = result + (select managerid from table where personid = l_loop);
        set l_loop = (select managerid from table where personid = l_loop);
    end while;
RETURN result;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `result` as a string.  Then you use addition.  No wonder your code is not doing what you expect.

Perhaps `concat()` is what you want:

```
    set result = concat_ws(',', result, (select managerid from table where personid = l_loop);
```

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and facepalm super hard right now.  Thank you so much!